# Xcode Afnterworking error

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking

I am getting a strange error while using afnetworking library.

```
../../../AFNetworking/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.h
```

I am getting error like "expected identifier or '(' with a single line"

Comment: may be you accidently out a character on that file. did you opened that file?

Comment: nop , i havn't put any characters . Checked it

Comment: The error message is clear, add an exception breakpoint and run it.  You can find the specific line of the error.

Comment: Exception not catching , not evan able to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by updating or reinstall all pod frameworks.